Why is My Custom Date Format Not Working in Angular Material Datepicker and How Can I Fix It?
To change the date format in the Material datepicker, I added the following configuration:
export const MY_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

and included it in the providers:
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS },

However, the date format still displays as MM/DD/YYYY.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
Check out the implementation here: StackBlitz.

First we should install @angular/material-moment-adapter
npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter

I am able to get it working by using the below import
import { provideMomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

Then we just need to add it to the providers array like so
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [provideMomentDateAdapter(MY_DATE_FORMATS)],
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatDatepickerModule],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {}

FULL CODE:
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {provideMomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker with custom formats */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-formats-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-formats-example.html',
  providers: [
    // Moment can be provided globally to your app by adding `provideMomentDateAdapter`
    // to your app config. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations
    // of our example generation script.
    provideMomentDateAdapter(MY_FORMATS),
  ],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class DatepickerFormatsExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());
}

Stackblitz Demo

Yes, it works. However, can I do it without using Moment.js? Can I use a native date function from Material instead?

@JackSud There is a problem in native date function as far as I can see when it comes to formatting, you can raise a github issue on angular github with them to understand why! here is a stackblitz for a working example!

Do you know if there is a way to have MY_FORMATS be dynamic so I can have different formats for different date pickers?

@SamRedmond create different component with different providers? Please raise a new question
